# How to open a Popup window which contains a graph written in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am using Django to implement a website and I would like to add a button such that when someone clicks it, it would open a Popup window which contains a graph written in javascript. And since I am writing the website in Django, I need to call a function in views.py to get the updated data and then draw the graph based on that. I originally want to update the graph on one page but now I would like to open a popup window. Could someone help me on how to modify the code so that the button would Popup a smaller window which contains the graph I implemented? Thanks!
Here is my code in main.html:

```
# I first have a button that could be clicked
<div class="col-lg-4">
 <p><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="display_list" id="display_list">Display List</button></p>
</div>
# here is the script I used to open up a Popup window such that the returned result would be displayed on that separate window
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#display_list").click(function(){
        $.get("display_list/", function(ret){
            $('#result').bPopup(); #I think probably I did this wrong?
         });
      });
    });
</script>
```

And here is the code I used to draw the graph in a separate html file(show_result.html):

```
<div id="result">
<script> javascript that draws a graph on html webpage. I pass the updated variable from the corresponding function in views.py to here by calling render(). </script>
</div>
```

Here is my function in the views.py:

```
def display_list(request):
   #some function implementation to get the result and put it in context
   return render(request, "show_result.html",context)
```

And this is the code in my url file:

```
url(r'^display_list/$', views.display_list, name='display_list'),
```

Is it possible to Popup a div in html? And what should I do in my case?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you could use a modal; you seem to be using bootstrap anyway; check out the docs here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be two ways of performing the task that you want. Here are the methods.

**Version 1 (The synchronous way)**
 
Suppose you have a url say `/x/` which opens `main.html`. So you can add whatever data, graph needs to the `context` on a `GET` call. Example:

```
def x(request):
    context = {}
    # Add data that is needed to draw the graph, in your context
    return render(request, "main.html",context)
```

Now you have the data that is needed to draw your graph, in your `main.html`'s `context`. Now you can simply use a Bootstrap modal to draw your graph in a pop up.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <p><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"id="display_list">Display List</button></p>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

You don't need the click event listener on `#display_list` since Bootstrap handles that.

```
<script>
    // Put your graph logic here and use '#modal-body' to render the graph
</script>
```

**Version 2 (The Async way)** 
In this case we have already opened the page on `/x/` and we will get data from `/display_list/` via an `AJAX` `GET` call.

```
def display_list(request):
    ''' Function to return data in json format to ajax call '''
    context = {}
    #Get all data required to draw the graph and put it in context

    return JsonResponse(context)
```

Since when you click the button you want to send `AJAX` request and then open the modal, you need to remove `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` from the button to prevent it from opening. Change the button to:

```
<p><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="display_list">Display List</button></p>
```

Now you can hit the url `/display_list/` to get your data. In your `main.html` add the Bootstrap modal element as in **version 1**. Now add the following Javascript to `main.html` to get the data.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#display_list").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var modalBody = $("#modal-body");
            // AJAX call to get the data
            $.ajax({
                url: '/display_list/',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    console.log(data);
                    // Add your graph logic here and use modalBody to draw on it
                }
            });

            //Now display the modal
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**NOTE** 
Remember to add Bootstrap's CSS and JS files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Example** 
So I will be going by **version 1** here in the example. I am using the graph provided [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292)
**Step 1:** Your `view x` should look like this:

```
def x(request):
    context = {}
    links = [
        {'source': "Microsoft", 'target': "Amazon", 'type': "licensing"},
        {'source': "Microsoft", 'target': "HTC", 'type': "licensing"},
        {'source': "Samsung", 'target': "Apple", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Motorola", 'target': "Apple", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Nokia", 'target': "Apple", 'type': "resolved"},
        {'source': "HTC", 'target': "Apple", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Kodak", 'target': "Apple", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Microsoft", 'target': "Barnes & Noble", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Microsoft", 'target': "Foxconn", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Oracle", 'target': "Google", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Apple", 'target': "HTC", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Microsoft", 'target': "Inventec", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Samsung", 'target': "Kodak", 'type': "resolved"},
        {'source': "LG", 'target': "Kodak", 'type': "resolved"},
        {'source': "RIM", 'target': "Kodak", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Sony", 'target': "LG", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Kodak", 'target': "LG", 'type': "resolved"},
        {'source': "Apple", 'target': "Nokia", 'type': "resolved"},
        {'source': "Qualcomm", 'target': "Nokia", 'type': "resolved"},
        {'source': "Apple", 'target': "Motorola", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Microsoft", 'target': "Motorola", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Motorola", 'target': "Microsoft", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Huawei", 'target': "ZTE", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Ericsson", 'target': "ZTE", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Kodak", 'target': "Samsung", 'type': "resolved"},
        {'source': "Apple", 'target': "Samsung", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Kodak", 'target': "RIM", 'type': "suit"},
        {'source': "Nokia", 'target': "Qualcomm", 'type': "suit"}
    ]
    context['links'] = links
    return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

**Step 2:** In your `main.html` add the following to your `<head>` tag.

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>    
    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #666;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    #licensing {
        fill: green;
    }

    .link.licensing {
        stroke: green;
    }

    .link.resolved {
        stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
    }

    circle {
        fill: #ccc;
        stroke: #333;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    text {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        pointer-events: none;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
    }
    .modal-dialog {
        width: 63% !important;
    }
</style>
```

**Step 3:** This will be your `<body>` tag in `main.html`, in this you will need to have a global `var links = {{ links|safe }}` variable. We cant shift the script to a separate file since django template tag wont work there.

```
<body>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <p><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="display_list">Display List</button></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        var links = {{ links|safe}};
        var nodes = {};

        // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
        function tick() {
          path.attr("d", linkArc);
          circle.attr("transform", transform);
          text.attr("transform", transform);
        }

        function linkArc(d) {
          var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
              dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
              dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
          return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
        }

        function transform(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        }

        // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
        links.forEach(function(link) {
          link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
          link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
        });

        var width = 860,
            height = 500;

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
            .links(links)
            .size([width, height])
            .linkDistance(60)
            .charge(-300)
            .on("tick", tick)
            .start();

        var svg = d3.select("#modal-body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
            // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
            svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
            .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
          .enter().append("marker")
            .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
            .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
            .attr("refX", 15)
            .attr("refY", -1.5)
            .attr("markerWidth", 6)
            .attr("markerHeight", 6)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
          .append("path")
            .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

        var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
            .data(force.links())
          .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
            .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

        var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
            .data(force.nodes())
          .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", 6)
            .call(force.drag);

        var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
            .data(force.nodes())
          .enter().append("text")
            .attr("x", 8)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });


    </script>
</body>
```

Thats it you are ready to go. Look carefully you don' require to add a click event to `#display_list` as Bootstrap handles all that.

Here's a [JSBin demo](https://jsbin.com/rohoba/edit?html,css)

Comment: Thank you so much! I am trying your method and I am not sure how to use modalBody to draw the graph. I am using this graph, code included (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292) and the only variable I am changing/updating is var links. Could you give me an example on how to combine it with modalBody?

Comment: And I used an updated links(from views.py) in the script. So for example, I did `var links = {{ updated_list | safe }};` do I also include this into the `<script>` section?

Comment: @Lynn you need `var links = {{ updated_list | safe }};` in your `<script>` since your `links` coming from the view needs to be stored somewhere, so that you can access it. Checkout the answer I have updated it.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!!! It works now! But it doesn't work on my computer if I put `source` as a string in `def x(request):`. So I ended up having an extra list in views.py and then updating it in the javascript. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's completely possible using bootstrap modals, here's documentation about it :
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

And a sample code :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="id_you_want_for_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> Title you want </h4>
      </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
               <!-- Your Graph here  -->
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do not forget to include the bootstrap js and css files in your project :

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you! It helps but I am trying to include graph into the modal since I need to call function in views.py each time to get the updated data.